# Coding simple HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me. Im new to java and HTML but i was trying to make a simple application that takes an input from a drop down list of motor sizes and converts them from HP to KW. I cannot get a result printed. I ran out of ideas, my small code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<fieldset class="Desired">
    <legend>Input Supply:</legend>
    <center>
    <div class="form">
    <p><b>Motor(HP):</b></p>
    <form action="/action_page.php" id= "motork">
        <select id="motor" name="motor">
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="60">60</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </div>

    <center>
    <br>
    <input onclick="converttokw()" type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn1" > 
    </center>

    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    var motorsize= new Array();
        motor["24"]=24;
        motor["30"]=30;
        motor["60"]=60;

    function converttokw() {
            var kw=0;
            var HP= document.forms["motork"];
            var selectedHP = theForm.elements["motor"];
            kw = motorsize[selectedHP.value]*746;
            return kw;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = kw

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript

Comment: after you return a value in converttokw() nothing else will be executed on that function

Comment: Also your variable names keep changing, e.g. it looks like `motor` and `motorsize` are supposed to be the same.

Comment: also HTML is malformed, the first center tag is not being closed. Fieldset tag not being closed.

Comment: Shortened: http://plnkr.co/edit/DeutcaAQdlHMuyMDfK6X?p=preview

Comment: The most important lesson here is to realize exactly how nonsensical that array is. Imagine you'd want to convert five strings to a number. Or ten. You're sitting in front of a computer. How likely is it you have to do it by hand...?

Comment: @derloopkat Didn't notice that. The `<center>` element is obsolete: https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a fully corrected copy. Keep your variable names consistent. You didn't need the motor array at all, as JavaScript is quite happy to coerce `"24"`, a string, into a number for multiplication. Also:

- Look into CSS, `<centre>` is obsolete, and `<b>` is not appropriate for making headings.
- Put `<script>` tags in a `<head>` tag if possible.
- I've made sure that your HTML tags nest correctly, this is important.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <fieldset class="Desired">
      <legend>Input Supply:</legend>
      <center>
        <div class="form">
          <h3>Motor(HP):</h3>
          <form id="motork">
            <select id="motor" name="motor">
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="60">60</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>

        <br>
        <input onclick="converttokw()" type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn1">

        <p id="demo"></p>
      </center>
    </fieldset>

    <script>
      function converttokw() {
        var kw = 0;
        var HP = document.getElementById("motor");
        kw = HP.value * 746;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = kw;
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete: https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: @Rob Thanks! Now fixed.

Comment: You missed one.

Comment: @Rob `<b>` isn't obsolete, it's just strongly discouraged in many situations. I guess that's what you meant?

Comment: I'm saying you missed one of the center tags. I said nothing about `<b>`

Answer (score 3):

No `<center>`, no `<b>`, no `<br>` when used only for vertical spacing– you don’t style with HTML. You style with CSS. But you have all the time to learn that.

Java is that old Sun technology thing that used to run on webpages via applets. Now it’s used to make smartphone software. But here in browsers, it’s a totally different language and it’s called JavaScript. Do not make confusion.

Now for your problem, first open your best ally: the console. Key is F12. The console will show you the errors in your script if any, and messages you log by calling `console.log`.

With your new friend the console, you can already see that you have an undefined variable: `theForm`. I guess it should be your HTML form, except there is none in your page. Not a problem, you can reach the `"motor"` element with its id:

```
var selectedHP = document.getElementById("motor");
```

Your second best ally is the [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which costs almost nothing– adding a string `'use strict';` at the beginning of your script– and shows you even more errors.

Add my advice to pritesh agrawal’s one and you should get your code running.
One last suggestion: use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when you don’t need to have HTML code parsed. When you need HTML code parsed, don’t use `innerHTML`. [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is more efficient in any situation.

Comment: @Watlin, you've linked to French MDN, possibly an English link is better for SO? Excellent answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

can you try below

remove the return ( i cant understand why it is there is 1st place. )

```
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = kw;
```

Please read above commeents as well , 
below is the working code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<fieldset class="Desired">
<legend>Input Supply:</legend>
<center>
<div class="form">
<p><b>Motor(HP):</b></p>
 <form action="/action_page.php" id= "motork">
    <select id="motor" name="motor">
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="60">60</option>
    </select>
 </form>
</div>
</center>
<center>
<br>
<input onclick="converttokw()" type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn1" > 
</center>

<p id="demo"></p>
</fieldset>
<script>
    var motorsize= new Array();
    motorsize["24"]=24;
    motorsize["30"]=30;
    motorsize["60"]=60;

 function converttokw() {
        var kw=0;
        var HP= document.forms["motork"];
        var selectedHP = HP.elements["motor"];
        kw = motorsize[selectedHP.value]*746;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = kw
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have removed the return and replaced existing line with the line above and still wont display

Comment: please try with the code i provided, it worked fine for me , your HTML was poorly formed and i fixed few bits and pieces in the function

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the function that converts HP to KW for you.

```
function converttokw() {
  var selector = document.getElementById("motor");
  var HP = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
  var KW = HP * 746;
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("demo");
  paragraph.innerHTML = KW;
}
```

Explanation:

1. First, I select your `<select>` element with the ID of `motor`
2. Then, I get the selected Item from the `<select>` Element
3. Then, I convert the KW to HP using your forumala
4. Then, I select your paragraph with the ID of `demo`
5. And lasty, I change it's inner HTML to be the converted KWs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fieldset class="Desired">
  <legend>Input Supply:</legend>
  <center>
    <div class="form">
      <p><b>Motor(HP):</b></p>
      <form action="/action_page.php" id="motork">
        <select id="motor" name="motor">
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>

    <center>
      <br>
      <input onclick="converttokw()" type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn1">
    </center>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function converttokw() {
        var kw = 0;
        var e = document.getElementById("motor");
        var HP=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        kw = HP* 746;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = kw
      }

    </script>
```

[See it in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywdOBr)